# Wrapping code inside styled component in React.js yields unexpected results on show password button click

Tags: styled-components

```
App.js:

import './App.css';

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Register from './Components/Register';
import Greet from './Components/Greet';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  
    this.state = {
       isRegistered: false,
       name: null,
       email: null,
       password: null,
       showPass:false,
    }
  }
  registerHandler=(e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const name = e.target.name.value;
  const email = e.target.email.value;
  const password = e.target.password.value;
  this.setState({ isRegistered: true,name,email,password});
  }
  showPassHandler=()=>{
    
    this.setState({showPass:!(this.state.showPass)});

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.isRegistered?<Greet name={this.state.name} email={this.state.email}/>:<Register submit={this.registerHandler} click ={this.showPassHandler} showPass={this.state.showPass}/>}
      </div>
    )


  }
}



export default App;
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
Register.js:


import React,{useState} from 'react'
import Styled from "styled-components";
export default function Register(props) {
    const btnStyle={
        backgroundColor:"red",
        color:"white",
        
    }
    
    
  
//     const savePassword=(val)=>{

// show=val.target.value;
// val.target.value=show;


// inputRef.current.focus();
// val.target.focus();
// console.log(show);
// setPass(show);
//     }
    // console.log(show);
    let btnText;
    const btnClasses = ["btn","m-1","mt-2"];
    if(props.showPass===true)
    {
        btnStyle.backgroundColor = "green";
        btnText="hide password";
        
        btnClasses.push("btn-primary");
       
    }
    else{
        btnText="show password";
       
        
        btnClasses.push("btn-danger");
    }
   const StyledButton = Styled.button
   `
    background-color: ${(props)=>props.bgColor};
    color: white;
    display:${(props)=>props.flag==="1"?"inline-block":"block"};
    width:${(props)=>props.flag==="1"?"45%":"100%"};
    margin:5px;

    `
    const StyledRegisterContainer = Styled.div`
    width:600px;
    &:hover {box-shadow:0px 0px 5px grey};
    @media (min-width:0px) and (max-width:600px) {
        width:300px;
    };
 `;
    //register-container=> was class inside most outer div
  return (
    
    <StyledRegisterContainer className='container card mt-4 p-3 '>
    
        <h1 className='text-center'>
            Registration Form
        </h1>
<form onSubmit={props.submit}>
    <div className='form-group'>
        <label className='control-label' htmlFor='name'>Name:</label>
<input type='text' name='name' className='form-control'/>
    </div>
    <div className='form-group'>
        <label className='control-label' htmlFor='email'>Email:</label>
<input type='email' name='email' className='form-control'/>
    </div>
    <div className='form-group'>
        <label className='control-label' htmlFor='password'>password:</label>
<input  type={props.showPass?"text":"password"} name='password' required className='form-control' />
    </div>
    <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary mt-2 m-1'>
Register
    </button>
    <button  type ="button" className={btnClasses.join(" ")}  onClick={props.click}>
       
{btnText}
    </button>
    <br/>
    <StyledButton flag="1" bgColor="orange">Login</StyledButton>
    <StyledButton flag="1" bgColor="blue">Login</StyledButton>
    <StyledButton flag="0" bgColor="brown">Login</StyledButton>
</form>

    </StyledRegisterContainer>

  )
}
//style = {btnStyle}//it was inside button =>show password
```

inside Register.js file everything was working perfect but when I wrapped the code inside StyledRegisterContainer(a styled component) the functionality of show password button is disturbed and the moment I click on show password button the text from input box disapears.
I want my code to work even after wrapping it inside the above mentioned styled component.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with styled-components, but according to their documentation, it seems like you're importing `Styled` instead of `styled`

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
```

https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#installation

Comment: I tried it its not the solution